# How to get specific data from REST API?

Tags: node.js, json, api

I am trying to retrieve the number of cases with covid through this API: https://covidtracking.com/api/states

I have the following code:

```
function main(params) {

    if(!params) { return { error : "Please provide a valid action for the Cloud Function." } }

      if(!params.stateCode) { return { error : "Please provide a valid state code."} }

      else {
        const stateCode = params.stateCode;

        var request = require('request-promise');

        var options = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': 'https://covidtracking.com/api/states?state=' + stateCode,
            'headers': { },
            'body': { },
                json: true
            }

        return request(options).then(function (body) {
            return {message: body}
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
      }

}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to retrieve the json data that I need?

Error:

{
"error": "Please provide a valid state code."
}

Comment: If it doesn't work, please provide us with the errors it generates.

Comment: are you building the request query string correctly? It seems in your code that you are missing an "equal".. for example https://covidtracking.com/api/states?state=AK

Comment: I get this error back Please provide a valid state code.
@BeNdErR It still isn't successful

Comment: How are you passing in the params object to your `main` function? It could be that you're missing the `stateCode` property. It should look something like this `{stateCode: "CA"}`

Comment: debug your code and check which value you are passing to the api. The error code is quite clear, you are probably passing an invalid state code.

Comment: ah damn it should be lowercase letters